# Auslander's original work on isolated singularities and Serre functors

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, singularity

> (Quoted from [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287591/serre-duality-graded-singularity-category):) Let $R$ be a local Gorenstein ring of Krull dimension $d$ with an isolated singularity. Define the singularity category $D_{\rm sg}(R)$ as the Verdier quotient $D^{\rm b}(R)/{\rm Perf}(R)$. Then, **a famous result of Auslander** says that the shift by $[d-1]$ is a Serre functor for $D_{\rm sg}(R)$.

I've tried my best to find a reference of Auslander's original work, while I've only found a [paper by Murfet](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/residues-and-duality-for-singularity-categories-of-isolated-gorenstein-singularities/9F55D98BE8ADE66DB53F190474D44D0B) which referred Auslander's result to [[Aus78]](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=480688), which has hundreds of pages and I have no idea how it may relate to isolated singularities or Serre functors.

I think I should look for a formula like this:
$${\rm Hom}_{{\rm stable} L(\Lambda)}(M, N)\cong {\rm Hom}_{{\rm stable}L(\Lambda)}(N, \Omega^{d-1}M)',$$
but I couldn't find it.